# Placing buttons under a grid

Tags: java, swing, grid, jbutton

I am trying to position 2 JButtons under a grid of 9x9, but when I add the buttons, the grid is changed to accomodate the buttons, placing everything, including the buttons in a rectangle.

What i want is to have a grid and two buttons *below* the grid itself.

mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, BORDER_WIDTH));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

```
    for (int i = 0; i < subPanels.length; i++)
    {

      for (int j = 0; j < subPanels[i].length; j++)
      {
        subPanels[i][j] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        subPanels[i][j].setBorder(
          BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, BORDER_WIDTH));
        mainPanel.add(subPanels[i][j]);  
          }
    }
    buttonPanel.add(clear);
    buttonPanel.add(solve);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
```

The buttonPanel is what is supposed to be under the mainPanel..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is probably to put your mainPanel into the center of a BorderLayout, and then put the buttonPanel in the south.

Also, you're currently setting the GridLayout for your buttonPanel to 1 row x 1 column. You should probably set the layout before adding the buttons, and set it to 1 row x 2 columns.

Comment: How do i do that? Set them to center and south?

Comment: Try looking at the documentation for BorderLayout

Answer (score 0):

Every component on a form has a parent. If you place button1 on form1, button1.parent will be 'form1'.

change the parent of the buttons you want to the appropriate parent